# Does ssh-keygen -y work with PuTTY generated keys?

Tags: ssh, putty

Possibly a dumb question, and I'm prepared for downvotes, but haven't had luck finding the answer on my own.

I'm using PuTTY Key Generator to create an SSH key of type ED25519.  After I've added a passphrase and saved the key off, I test that the passphrase works by using `ssh-keygen -y -f <filename>.ppk`, [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411457/how-do-i-verify-check-test-validate-my-ssh-password)

I always receive the following message: 
`Load key "<filename>.ppk": incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key`

I know the passphrase is correct.  I've recreated the key a half-dozen times, including leaving off the passphrase entirely.

Is it just that ssh-keygen cannot work with putty generated keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no. you can convert from openssh to putty format though.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use